ESP32 PCB Review
I am currently designing a PCB to be manufactured. This version is my attempt at a working prototype. I am new to PCB design but am open to accepting any help I can get!
My part is meant to function alongside other parts. Function: ESP32-C3 connects to WiFi network and communicates with the AP. The board also monitors the battery level and makes the buzzer beep when it is too low. The programming pins are meant to be used with a serial to ttl adapter. Reset button intentionally not broken out. Unsure of how to break out boot button to put chip into mode that is ready to read code or if it can be done automatically. USB-C used to recharge battery. I chose to make my own board instead of using a premade one because of space, WiFi range, and power consumption limitations.
My questions:

Do I need to break out the boot button? If so, how should I do that?
Should I break out the reset button after all? I intended to just disconnect power if I need to reset and then after that, attach the battery for semi-permanent implementation.
Did I use the MTMS pin correctly for ADC? How would that correlate to code (i.e. what GPIO number)? I plan to code in Arduino, which I have some experience with, I just haven't seen a pin like this before.
Is there a boot up configuration I need to be aware of (i.e. pull up resistors in specific places)?
Any other glaringly obvious problems? I would like to finish this in as few iterations as possible.

Thanks!

If you want to save space you can use the USB-C port to program the MCU. You don't need the 4 pins UART connector. You have to connect D+ and D- to GPIO18 and GPIO19. Look for the ESP32C3-WROOM datasheet (the module) and check the sections: 5-Module schematic and 6-Peripheral schematics. Review this and also the rest of the elements of the board. You can just follow most of both schematics, except what you don't need. Also check a proper schematic for the USB-C connector, with all the data pins.

I would put both the reset and the boot buttons. In some cases you will need to use the boot button to be able to program the MCU.

Your pcb design is not viable. component choice,layout,track widths have issues. Espressif have guidelines, checklists and examples of how to layout the pcb and component requirements. Two layer pcb won’t cut it.  I’d suggest you use a module.

@Kartman Can you explain in further detail exactly why it won't wok?

You’ve put the components on the board and hooked them up with no regard to the critical RF and power requirements. It is not the type of circuit to cut your teeth on. Refer to the Espressif documents on pcb layout.

@Kartman Thank you for your help. I revised the design and made a new one based on your recommendations. Would you mind taking a look at them? Here is the new project: [https://oshwlab.com/bosoxkid33/skillsedp-receiver-ver-3_copy]

I don’t want to come across as negative, but there’s not many positives with the pcb layout. You’ve chosen a very difficult task to begin with. For low frequency circuits, the pcb layout is not very critical. Assuming you wire everything up correctly and size your pcb tracks to carry the current involved, then you’re home free.
However, as frequencies increase, the challenge takes a turn as now your pcb tracks and layout become invisible components in your circuit. There’s capacitance between your tracks, the tracks become inductors and the board thickness can play a significant role. WiFi is 2.45GHz so it’s well into the microwave region. Microwave design is a specialist area. Whilst you don’t need to be a specialist for this pcb design, you do need to be aware that there are dragons and you’d be best to copy a tested layout.
You need to decide whether you want to do a full custom layout and go into battle or take the safer road and just use a module. Personally, I just use a module - all the evil has been taken care of by others. I can then concentrate on the bits and pieces I want to add. For your design, you might be concerned with the physical size of using a module. That is an engineering decision - big, but more likely to work or small and expect failure. Choose your poison. There are a number of different modules available, so I’d looking for one that is hopefully small enough. Or the size constraint is arbitrary, in which case make your device larger.
If we ignore the evil RF side of the layout, we still have some dragons to slay. The ESP32 is a high speed device and can draw in excess of 200mA in fast pulses. What does that mean for the pcb layout? Firstly, careful choice of bypass capacitors, their placement and the track length and width. The simple solution is to refer to a known design and layout then copy it. If Espressif use a particular part - then you use it.
Seemingly simple components like capacitors are not as simple as you’d think.
Just because the schematic says 10uF 25V, that’s not enough information. Parameters like voltage derating, size, ESL and ESR can be critical. With the performance of the ESP32 the finer details do matter. Get it wrong and your device might be unreliable or simply not work.
With voltage regulators, placement and spec of the required capacitors is again critical.
Chip manufacturers will usually have reference designs and pcb layout suggestions. Even experienced people will only deviate from this carefully.
Your layout fails the above. The voltage regulator has thin tracks and not the required capacitors close by.
You would really want to use a four layer pcb for all of the above reasons as well as making the layout easier and more compact. The gnd/0V signals should use thick, short tracks and connect to the groundplane layer. 3V3 and power tracks also should be thick. 0.2mm wide tracks are for connecting the low current signals.
The buzzer placement is not optimal. The groundplane needs to extend up to the base of the antenna.
The evil part is the RF from the esp32 to the antenna. This is usually done as a ‘coplanar waveguide’ and there’s online calculators for this. You’ll need the specs for the actual pcb material for this. This info is provided by the pcb manufacturer. If you look at the Espressif reference design for their modules, you’ll see carefully designed tracks and spacing along with via stitching to make sure the WiFi signal has a smooth ride to the antenna.
My other suggestion is to tidy up the schematic. I see it as random bits and pieces. This seems to be a trend that has emerged that is near unreadable to experienced people - we need to mentally connect all the dots to make sense of it. The circuit starts at the USB connector and ends at the antenna. Draw the schematic so there’s a flow. Less likely to make mistakes with a readable schematic.

For the glaring problems, a non-exhaustive list includes at least the following items:
You don't have a single capacitor on the VBUS or VBAT supplies. There is no protection circuitry for battery. No USB-C supply will provide 5V to this device as it can't be detected by the supply. Your battery will be drained quickly by the voltage measurement divider.
Sorry I have no answers to if you want or need some boot or reset buttons. It depends what you want to achieve with them or can live without them.
For the boot configuration, it will be in the data sheet if there is one.
